# Passing Context from one Mono to another - Context is empty

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to pass context from one Mono to another, and access it later, but obviously I do something wrong.
Thank you

```java
Mono<String> hello = Mono.just("Empty").subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("message","hellooooo"));
 
Mono<String> world = Mono.subscriberContext().map( ctx -> (String)ctx.get("message"));

world.subscribe(s -> System.out.println("\n Monos content: " + s));
```

And this is the error I got:

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context is empty
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Context is empty
    at reactor.util.context.Context0.get(Context0.java:42) ~[reactor-core-3.4.14.jar:3.4.14]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.map(Mono.java:3411)
...
```

As mentioned in the comments, it is because they are not in the same reactive flow.
But then - how the context is passed when I implement my own Filter(implements WebFilter) and return:

```java
return webFilterchain.filter(exchange).subscriberContext(c->c.put("key","value-key"));
```

After this, the context is visible in any controller, just like this:

```java
Mono<String> parameter= Mono.subscriberContext().map(s->s.get("key"));
```

What happened, that context is now visible in my parameter variable?
In documentation I can see, that filter method in WebFilterChain does some special delegation of the context "Delegate to the next WebFilter in the chain.". But not sure, what happened that it is visible in my custom "parameter" mono. How context was passed, and can I do something similar also with my custom reactive flows?

Comment: You need to construct reactive flow. In your code hello is not connected to world. [Reactor 3 Reference Guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#context) includes good examples.

Comment: I saw that but thought that it can be used also differently. I.e. put something into the context in one place, and then read from it in another place. 
Like this article (and many similar articles) - where in ReactiveRequestContextFilter I can set the context and then in another class - ReactiveRequestContextHolder, I can read the context. 
https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-01/webflux-get-request-anywhere/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: It's very different from the imperative programming. The whole idea of reactive is to build reactive flow using set of operators and then  subscribe to it. Spend some learning basics of the reactive.[Assembly vs Subscription]( https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription) could be a good starting point to understand the idea.

Comment: as pointed out, hello is not used in the above code which means no context from hello is passed down to world, which means when you subscribe the context is empty. You can put things in one place and read them in another place... IF they are in the same reactive flow. Which your code example isn't

Comment: And yes, I read the documentation, and can see, that filter method in WebFilterChain does some special delegation of the context "Delegate to the next WebFilter in the chain.". But not sure, what happened that it is visible in my custom "parameter" mono.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other have stated in comments, in your example you are creating two totally disconnected `Mono`s. One that *writes* to its context, and one that *reads* from (the default, ie. empty) context.

Context is only accessible if the read and write steps are part of a single reactive chain of operators.

Spring WebFlux ensures that this is the case, ie as long as you do delegate in the webFilterChain, Spring ensures that the operators you apply are part of a single chain that ties the request / subscription at the bottom and the `Flux` or `Mono` from the `@Controller` at the top, so you can read context inside the controller.